# Error -3 while decompressing: invalid stored block lengths

Tags: python, url, scrapy

I am scraping a website and it contains many URLs from which O need to fetch data.
I used XPath and fetched all the `href`s (URLs) and saved in to a list. I looped this list and yielded a request. Below is my spider code,

```
class ExampledotcomSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "exampledotcom"
   allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]
   start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/movies/city.html"]


   def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       cinema_links = hxs.select('//div[@class="contentArea"]/div[@class="leftNav"]/div[@class="cinema"]/div[@class="rc"]/div[@class="il"]/span[@class="bt"]/a/@href').extract()
       for cinema_hall in cinema_links:
            yield Request(cinema_hall, callback=self.parse_cinema)


   def parse_cinema(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       cinemahall_name = hxs.select('//div[@class="companyDetails"]/div[@itemscope=""]/span[@class="srchrslt"]/h1/span/text()').extract()
       ........
```

Here, for example, I had 60 URLs in the list, and for about 37 URLs are not downloaded: for these, an error message appeared:

```
2012-06-06 14:00:12+0530 [exampledotcom] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.example.com/city/Cinema-Hall-70mm-%3Cnear%3E-place/040PXX40-XX40-000147377847-A6M3>: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid stored block lengths
2012-06-06 14:00:12+0530 [exampledotcom] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.example.com/city/Cinema-Hall-35mm-%3Cnear%3E-place/040PXX40-XX40-000164969686-H9C5>: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid stored block lengths
```

Only for some URLs Scrapy is downloading, and for the remainder, I do not understand what's happening and what's wrong with my code.

Can anyone please suggest me how to remove these errors?

Comment: Would you please share how did you disable HttpCompressionMiddleware ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think anything is wrong with your code.

- Error -3 while decompressing: invalid stored block lengths
- CRC check failed 0x471e6e9a != 0x7c07b839L
- Error -3 while decompressing: invalid block type

All these errors seem to be related to gzip decompression. I think the site you are trying to access has response header `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`

> gzip An encoding format produced by the file compression program
>   "gzip" (GNU zip) as described in RFC 1952 [25]. This format is a
>   Lempel-Ziv coding (LZ77) with a 32 bit CRC.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression

So i think it's just a broken web-server hosting the page(s) scrapy is trying to download.

UPDATE:

Try to disable [HttpCompressionMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpcompression)

Comment: :Thanks this is very useful, yes when i run one of the site in the list for example with "scrapy shell "url_link" ", it is showing the following error

Comment: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/gzip.py", line 252, in read
self._read(readsize)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/gzip.py", line 303, in _read
uncompress = self.decompress.decompress(buf)
 zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid distance too far back

Comment: so is there any solution to make the scrapy download the response from all the URL's

Comment: Also some times scrapy is downloading the response for some url and sometimes not for the same url, can i know how to achieve this through code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to disable HttpCompressionMiddleware (see the link in my answer)

Comment: Thank very much that worked after disabling HttpCompressionMiddleware